# is there a possibility for cmake to install different resources to different/multiple "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX" folders

Tags: cmake

I have multiple resources, I want to install them to different places using cmake,
there is one problem,
the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` stays the same during all the project, but I want to install to folders outside `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

I tried to use a separate cmake script for the different install, and inside it I use

```
function(INSTALL_TO_OTHER_DIR INSTALL_PREFIX)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Some_Directory" DESTINATION  ${INSTALL_DIR})
endfunction()

INSTALL_TO_OTHER_DIR(${})
```

inside the script, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` seems to be updated to `INSTALL_PREFIX`, but this does not take effect on the install process, I find all the resources in the same folder.

any ideas.

Comment: "but I want to install to folders outside `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`." - **DO NOT DO THIS**. It's as close to a mortal sin as software distribution has.

Comment: If you need multiple unrelated destinations, set the prefix to `/` and provide overrides via cache variables for every destination. The `GNUInstallDirs` module provides some standard ones.

Comment: Trying to change the install location by modifying `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is a bad idea.In fact in general you should avoid using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in your cmake project at all. Trying this kind of modification makes your project confusing and furthermore it'll mess up all `cpack` functionality and `cmake --install ... --prefix ...` functionality: cpack does a local installation into the binary dir first before running the packager and it does so by overwriting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for the install scripts.You want to avoid installing anything outside the designated dir(file permissions)

Comment: @fabian is right... I would even say that practically any use of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` inside the CMakeLists.txt is a bug.